# QGIS - Form builder how to show a new box when another is checked

Tags: qgis, lizmap

I wonder if in the form builder of a layer in QGIS one could set a dependency to a box to another. [image]

When I'll check the box *Inhabitants*, I would have the *Type of housing* appearing.

[image]

I am using Lizmap for the visual on the web, the second photo shows the render I would achieve when *Inhabitants* is checked.

Comment: Documentation on this feature: https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/layer_properties/attributes_form.html#advanced-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy done in QGIS if you use a Drag & Drop Form. Just add an container from type `groupbox` and put the controls into that. Then you can control the visibility of the group with an expression, in the picture below it is a checkbox survey, if the value will be true the container with coordinate fields will be visible.

[image]

[image]

[image]